# Is there any SSH OS support in Android?

Tags: security, ssh

I am reading the article [Jolla and SSH push Sailfish Secure as “European alternative” mobile OS](https://gigaom.com/2015/03/02/jolla-and-ssh-push-sailfish-secure-as-european-alternative-mobile-os/). 
I have used third-party applications for SSH in my phone but would like to have OS supported.

How can you get OS supported SSH in Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be a bit confused about the article you read. It's about an Android-compatible clone, which has nothing to do with the SSH communications protocol. The company mentioned has SSH in its name, and was founded by one of the original inventors of the SSH protocol, but doesn't "own" the SSH protocol or name, or the OpenSSH server.

As you've already found, you can have SSH in Android now simply by installing a SSH server or client on any Android device. It's "OS supported" just as much as HTTP is "OS supported" because you can use a web browser or a web server in Android. This new Android clone won't be any different in that respect.